# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_sqlite3_close", referenced

Tags: ios, sqlite, linker-errors

I'm new to objective-c and am getting this error when I add from sqlite3 calls in xcode.  Any one know what I can do to fix this error?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[InAppUtils get:] in libInAppUtils.a(InAppUtils.o)
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      -[InAppUtils get:] in libInAppUtils.a(InAppUtils.o)
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[InAppUtils get:] in libInAppUtils.a(InAppUtils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried adding the `libsqlite3.dylib` library but I can't find it on my system.  Is it required?  If so, how do I find it?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the SQLite library to your project. Select your project. Go to the Build Phases tab. Expand the "Link Binary with Libraries" section. Click on the + icon. Search for "sqlite". Add the library.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `libsqlite3.tbd` is the new `libsqlite3.dylib`.  I added it and everything worked.

Go to the Build Phases tab. Expand the "Link Binary with Libraries" section. Click on the + icon. Search for "sqlite". Add the library